# pyside2 QlistWidget turn off 'wrapping'

Tags: pyside2, qlistwidget

I have a QListWidget in PySide2 and I want to turn off the wrapping function. How do I disable that function?

[image]

Comment: Could you explain me better?, I don't understand your question

Comment: The items populate the list and if there are more items than can fit in the box, it wraps them into a second column rather then extending the list vertically and allowing the scroll bar to function.

Comment: provide a [MRE]

Comment: That is not the default behavior of a QListWidget, so I assume that some configuration of yours is generating what reinforces my request for MRE if you want help.

Comment: I am trying to recreate the behavior in a sharable size